# If A is a non singular matrix show that $(xA)^{-1} = \frac{1}{x}A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

If A is a non singular matrix show that $(xA)^{-1} = \frac{1}{x}A^{-1}$

I was trying:

because A is not singular then there exist $A^{-1}$ such that $A^{-1}A = I$ let A be a matrix such that $A=[a_{ij}]_{m\times n}$ and $(xA) = [xa_{ij}]_{m\times n}$ then:

$(xA)^{-1} = ([xa_{ij}])^{-1}_{m \times n} = \frac{1}{x}A^{-1}$

if this proof is correct can you help me improve it else why is this proof wrong?

Comment: Your proof is not correct: The last step $ ([xa_{ij}])^{-1}_{m \times n} = \frac{1}{x}A^{-1}$ is practically what you are been asked to prove.

Comment: This proof makes no sense. How did you conclude that $([xa_{ij}])^{-1}_{m \times n} = \frac{1}{x}A^{-1}$? It's not clear at all, that's what you have to prove. $(xA)^{-1}$ is by definition the inverse of $xA$. So you need to show that $\frac{1}{x}A^{-1}$ is an inverse of $xA$. Multiply the two matrices and show you get the identity. And by the way, an invertible matrix by definition has to be a square matrix. So change $m\times n$ to $n\times n$.

Comment: Why mess around with the $a_{ij}$ when you can proof it by simply apply the supposed invariant to te original?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have an explicit expression for the inverse, you just need to check that it *is* actually the inverse.

To do that you just have to show that $(xA)(\frac{1}{x}A^{-1}) = I$, which follows directly from distributivity of the product of a matrix and a scalar.

Comment: can you make the proof more formal please

Comment: @samsamradas The answer gives pretty much all you need. Why don't you try to write it more formally? If you have specific questions on how to do it then you can ask. The purpose of this forum is to help, not to do the homework.